# Tweepy Twitter API does not create friendship with first id in the list

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I am creating a list of ids from which I want tweepy to create a friendship. It works for the other ids in the list but not for the first.
How can I fix it?
Here is my code:

```
import tweepy
import time

consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True, compression=True)

users = [1432834552028962816, 1170672149616615424, 1432600808542117889]
for person in users:
    user = api.get_user(id=person)
    print(user.id)
    api.create_friendship(user.id)
```

I do not get any error, the code finishes succesfully, but when I check, it only followed the last 2 ids and not the first. Why? and how to fix it?